# How to receive a regular email listing all Twitter mentions of a specific word or keyword?

Tags: twitter

Searching Twitter for mentions of a word or multiple words can be a chore. Is there something that can be set up in Twitter that will email me a digest of search terms?

Or do I have to look for some kind of third-party service that provides daily or weekly emails featuring all mentions of a specific word or hashtag?

Answer (score 4):

[tweet alarm](http://www.tweetalarm.com/) might able to help you. I am using this to mail me everytime there is a **public tweet** mention about `particular word`.

Hopes this help.

Comment: This looks awesome. Awaiting results...

Comment: This works really well, thanks for the advice.

Comment: glad that it works :)

Comment: Actually, this only picks up a small percentage of all mentions. Any other suggestions? I am going to reopen this question until someone provides a more comprehensive option.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a site just for this purpose called https://www.MyTweetAlerts.com.
You can set up email alerts based on your custom criteria.

Comment: Thank you for including your affiliation with the product.  It would be better if you wrote why it's suited for this purpose, as it stands, it reads a bit like an advertisement.

Comment: I notice that you've put this same answer for 2 other questions as well.  Please don't use the site to "astroturf" your product.  Try to tailor each answer to the question that was asked, otherwise people are going to flag this as spam.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Those questions were very similar. I have edited the answer a little bit and will make modifications to the other ones as well. My product is made to monitor twitter and send emails based on keywords and other metrics so is good fit for SamtheBrand.